# Transform Pulkovo to WGS84

Tags: gdal

I have here a historical Polish map from 1928 entitled "Rozyszcze".
http://maps.mapywig.org/m/WIG_maps/series/025K_old/XXVIII-18-F_ROZYSZCZE_1928_LoC_G6520_s25_.R8.jpg

The coordinates given are "-5°06' na zach. od Pulkowa" and "50°55'".
I would convert these values to WGS84 using gdaltransform or Postgis st_transform, but I can't find a suitable EPSG.

I tried all 491 records from the spatial_ref_sys table that contain "Pulkovo" in the text, but no success.
-5°06' should result in about 25°13' in epsg 4326.

Does somebody has any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Georeferencing plain images is best achieved using GCPs. Once you have set up the GCPs, you can use `gdal_warp` to warp the image to a known projection using a polynomial interpolation.

Find the coordinates of at least 4 points lying on the parallels/meridians - both the pixel coordinates and the geographical coordinates. Load the image in an image viewer. IrfanView can do it.

Then do as explained here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/360187/what-is-the-proper-way-to-georeference-an-image-based-on-gcp-using-gdal-tools

Then you can use `gdal_warp` to warp it into EPSG:4326 or similar.